# How to catch finder alert?

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder

How can I catch and interfere if the Finder pops up an alert?
I thought it would be some notification in [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but was disappointed.

Which is the right way to do this?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: What are you trying to do? In general you cannot interfere with another application, which is good because the user would be pretty upset about that. There are [File System Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html) which allow you to be notified when file system changes occur. It will not, however, allow you to interfere with the user interface of the Finder (which is good).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right, interference would be pretty dangerous. I will give File System Events a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry you can't intercept another app's alert view. (at least not without breaking code signing and tinkering with the other app .. e.g. via some simbl plugin)

**there is no obvious and apple-conform way and this is a good thing!**